# How to setstate in one statefulwidget when a button is clicked in another statefulwidget?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have one parent statefulwidget that contains a TabBarView.
The child to this tabbarview are two different child statefulwidgets.

What I want to achieve is that if I press a button in one of those child statefulwidgets, it should animate the tabcontroller and also set state in the parent statefulwidget.

How to do that? Thanks

Comment: Add what you've tried please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Calling SetState() from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54786946/flutter-calling-setstate-from-another-class)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a function in the parent widget which changes the tab and sets the state, and then pass that as a parameter to the children widgets and call it when needed.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the below link
[Let the parent widget manages the widget’s state](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive#parent-managed)

Answer (score 0):

I think it will solve your problm

https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-communication-between-widgets-f5590230df1e